# When making a list by query request in GMail via C#, what's the "source"?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-api, gmail

Context: C#, JavaScript, ClearScript

I've written a plugin for my ClearScript-enabled JavaScript that connects to GMail. Everything's fine regarding OAuth2 etc. What's not working is a query against the inbox. If I request the inbox without a query, that gives me data, but I don't want millions of records.

```js
attach(".\\Plugin_GMail.dll")
var tuple = Plugin_GMail.GoogleMail.Mail.Mail_Authenticate(REDACTED)
var service = Plugin_GMail.GoogleMail.Mail.Mail_CreateService(tuple.Item1, "mail")
var request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");
var labels = request.Execute().Labels;
var before = new Date(2022,11,31).valueOf();
var after = new Date(2022,0,1).valueOf();
var res = Plugin_GMail.GoogleMail.Mail.Messages_ListByQuery(service, "me", "before:$b after:$a".replace("$b",before).replace("$a",after),true)
```

The code for Messages_ListByQuery is

```cs
        public static string Messages_ListByQuery(GmailService service, string userId, string query, bool debug = false)
        {
            if (debug) Debugger.Launch();
            var msgList = new List<Message>();

            var result = new JSONResponse();

            var request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
            request.MaxResults = 500;
            request.Q = query;
            request.LabelIds = "INBOX";

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {                   
                    var msgs = request.Execute().Messages;
                    if (msgs.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    msgList.AddRange(msgs);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    result.Error = e.Message;
                    break;
                }
            }
            result.Cargo = msgList;
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        }
```

So the response after executing the query-based List is

```json
{"Error":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source","Cargo":[],"Crew":null}
```

I have been through the documentation and can't find anything about "source". And there's nothing in the Playground about "source" either. Where next?

Comment: I strongly suspect if you start logging the exception instead of copying the error message and swallowing the rest, then look at your server logs, you'll find it's an error in a LINQ call. My *guess* is that `msgs` is null rather than an empty list, and so the `Count()` extension method is failing with that exception. It's hard to tell for sure without a stack trace though. (I'd strongly advise trying to get the code to work in a console app though - it'll be much easier to see exactly what's going on there.)

Comment: while (true)  <-- is going to loop for a long time.

Comment: Wow, I get a comment from @JonSkeet! If I wasn't already sitting down I'd say, "I think I need to sit down." Yes, enabling the checking is good idea. I've had a lot of success with that debugging Google Ads code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is telling it to just loop forever, getting the same page of results.

```
while (true)   // loop forever
        {
            try
            {                   
                var msgs = request.Execute().Messages;  // get first page of results
                if (msgs.Count() == 0)  
                {
                    break; // will never hit unless user has no messages. in their inbox at all.
                }
                msgList.AddRange(msgs);  // keeps adding first page of messages over and over.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result.Error = e.Message;
                break;
            }
        }
```

The line

```
var msgs = request.Execute().Messages;
```

Is just going to say run the request and get me messages.  Which will always return messages as your running the same request over and over.

The following line is just going to add the messages to your list.

```
msgList.AddRange(msgs);
```

So with the while true you are telling your app to just request the same 500 rows again and again forever.

You should instead look at using the next page token and getting the next page of results instead of the same results over and over.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Pardon me while I crawl under this rock ...

Comment: When you come back out check out pagestreamer [pagination with the google .net client library](https://www.daimto.com/pagination-google-net-client-library/)  I dont have an example for gmail but if you have any issues open a new question.